# Angular's subscribe not logging full error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to log an error from a subscribe, but the error seems... incomplete?

I've never seen this kind of problem, nor could I find anything on Google. The code is the following:

```
this._http.post(this.urlPath, email).subscribe(
    res => {
      // stuff
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err) // <- I need to log this
    }
  );
```

It works to an extent. When I open the browser's console, in order to check the error, what I get is this:

[image]

The thing is, it seems like there's missing information here. If I open the Network tab, the response for this same request looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the real response has more information. I've tried using `{observe: "response"}`, but to no avail. I should note that if I try using `fetch`, the response comes complete, but I'd rather use **HttpClient**.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you receive a http error status code you can't access to the payload returned by the service by the same way that in a success case. Is like an special object.

But you can acccess to it doing some like this, using a pipe in your service and an error handler. This is a minimal example of it:

```
your.service.ts
...

handleError(error) {
  return throwError(error.error);
}
return  this.http.get ... the rest of your request.pipe(
 catchError(this.handleError)
);
...
```

And where you consume your service, in err you can acces to full response that your error request contains.

```
 ...
 , error => {
   console.warn(error);        
 }
```

Or better than, you can throw the entire object to access to the error (response body) and the rest of params, like status code.

Comment: What does this mean?
It is absolutely impossible using HttpClient?
Why would that be a thing?

Comment: err => { console.log(err._body) }? That just logs undefined....

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer with more info, I hope it help you.